# Wordpress CSS & Media Query

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I am using a Wordpress theme and facing some challenges while changing the @media query for tab/mobile view lower than 961px screen size. Following is the link:

http://www.logopexcil.com on a higher resolution the header background image starting from very top but lower than 961px resolution it starts after topbar & nav bar. I tried with the following CSS but seems I am doing something wrong:

```css
@media (max-width: 961px) {
.has-header-type11 .blox.page-title-x,.parallax-sec 
.page-title-x, .has-header-type11 .video-sec .page-title-x {
   top:0!important;  
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From your description I'm understanding you need assistance with alignment. This CSS adjusts the container and header since they have to be reversed. Hope it helps.

```
@media (max-width: 961px) {
.has-header-type11 .blox.page-title-x,
.parallax-sec 
.page-title-x, 
.has-header-type11 .video-sec .page-title-x {top:0!important;}


  .top-bar {display: none;} /* this was taking up space */
  .container {position:relative;top: 70px;} /* in the HTML this is above header, so bump it down */
  #header.w-header-type-11 {position: relative !important;top: -155px;}
  #main-content.container {padding:0;} /* remove unneeded padding */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the problem: when the screen shrinks:

- `#header` loses `position: absolute
- the top bar becomes visible

Answer (score 0):

The image is a background image, so

```
@media (max-width: 961px)
.has-header-type11 .blox.page-title-x, .parallax-sec .page-title-x, .has-header-type11         
.video-sec .page-title-x {
    background-position-y: top !important;
}
```

The `.page-title-x` div already has an inline style, so the `!important` is required.